# What is visual studios 2013 used for?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xna

I am a student interested in game programming, and I have recently started to learn visual c#. I would eventually like to move onto platforms like XNA and unity, but for now my aim is to be able to program in c#. I am thinking of making a football simulation game like football manager or new star soccer.

My question is, what is visual studios used for in real life? Can you make games using it?

Comment: To keep up the football theme, Visual Studio is Notepad on steroids. You _mainly_ use it to write code. It has some other cool features though...

Comment: @Vajura oh yes you can use VS to program games... why couldn't you?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, I thought that XNA didn't work on versions newer that 2010.

Comment: @AndreiV I don't know much about XNA, but you don't have to use XNA to program games... There's SlimDX for instance if you want to stick to C#

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, of course, I totally agree, but the question was tagged with XNA and it was specifically mentioned in the text.

Comment: you should use monogame instead of XNA these days

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio is a [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), its a code editor with loads of features.
Visual C# (if you speak of the free c# code editor from MS) is a stripped version of Visual Studio, made for the C# language.

Yes, you can use it for making games, when it comes to the code parts.